# Adding $args to wp_schedule_event() causes hook to add infinitely to WP Cron

Tags: loop, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I'm working on calling my function from server cron instead of using WP Cron. The problem I occured is simple. When I add $args to `wp_schedule_event()` method, and check for the successfull addition in plugin called `WPCrontrol`, i see that on every page refresh the same hook is added over and over again.

I have a function called `generateXlsxFile()` to whom I need to pass one variable `boolean(true)`.
Steps I tried so far:
1) `if (!wp_next_scheduled('generateXlsxFile')){ wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'generateXlsxFile', array(true); }`
2)`add_action('generateXlsxFile', 'generateXlsxFile', 10 , 1);`

If I don't use `array(true)` in `wp_schedule_event()`, everything works as intended. If I add`array(true)`, it starts looping on adding hook over and over again. I have no idea what is causing this, because without arguments another `wp_schedule_event()` method is working fine.

 Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you include the full code for registering/handling  your cron event? It's difficult to debug the snippets you've provided, especially when they're formatted as bullet points. Also why do you need to pass `[ true ]`? If it always passes the same value can't you work around that? e.g. `add_action( 'generateXlsxFile', function() { generateXlsxFile( [true] ); }, 10 , 1);`? Or better yet a default value on the function argument?

Comment: I can' add a default value on function argument, because I use this function in various ways. You will see it in attached picture. But I tried your workaround and it worked. Amazing, thanks. Anyhow, I still have no idea what caused the loop. [code screenshot](https://imgur.com/ONIguhP)

Comment: See [this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_next_scheduled/#comment-1598) in the docs. "Not specifying the $args parameter in wp_next_scheduled but having $args for wp_schedule_event will cause many events to be scheduled (instead of just one)." Possibly the reverse is also true.

Comment: OMG, I literally read that comment dozen of times. Ofcourse, it works now. Thank you! I guess i was too tired to see the answer in front of me. Big thank again, mate! :)